# how to prevent "post accent" in input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keycode

I believe this is an easy one, but I couldn't find any answer after a couple of hours searching on google (maybe I wasn't able to use the correct words in the search :-P)

I have a javascript method that prevents the user to fill the textbox with other characters than numbers, as it can be seen in the code below, and it's used in KeyDown event:

```js
function checkNumberInput(e) {
  // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
  if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110]) !== -1 ||
      // Allow: Ctrl+A, Command+A
      (e.keyCode == 65 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) ||
      // Allow: home, end, left, right, down, up
      (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
    // let it happen, don't do anything
    return;
  }
  // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
  if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

The problem is that, if the user types accent characters that "waits" a second key (such as ~´`^), it appears in the textbox when a number is typed right after.

For example:

```
a) types 1 => [1________]
b) types ~ => [1________]
c) types 3 => [1~3______]
```

How can I prevent this from happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what if you add the keyUp event also?

Comment: On the end of the keyUp event, maybe you could scan the input's 'value' property for non-numeric characters, and remove them if found; maybe you could use `setTimeout()` to schedule a check of the 'value' property to be executed a few milisseconds after the keyUp...

Comment: I used @Al.G. method allied with the keyUp and it did the trick.    
I wanted to remove the "write-erase" effect, but I think it's impossible. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: @thiagoprzy look at my answer update. The demo does what you want. By the way, why don't you use `<input type=number>`?

Comment: @Al.G., the client doesn't want the "arrows" to increment and decrement the value that renders in the side of the box =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean that `'` and `a` are converted to `а́`? 
This is built in the system, you cannot change that.
What you can do is check the input after that. This way you'll also prevent paste with mouse:

```
$('input').on('keydown', checkNumberInput).on('blur focus', function(){
    var val = $('input').val();

    // now remove everything that is not allowed
    val = val.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g, '');

    $('input').val(val);
})
```

(The exact implementation is deffinitely not perfect, just to illustrate what's going on)

https://jsfiddle.net/5afwdhzx/

About really instant fix - give this closure a name and call it inside the keyDown function with some short delay, like @haroldo said above.

https://jsfiddle.net/5afwdhzx/1/

Comment: I wanted to remove the "write-erase" effect, but I think it's impossible, right? Well, the only change I made was change the event from "blur focus" to "keyup", in order to remove the accent rightaway. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @thiagoprzy Answer edited, now should work as expected.